# How to run .lnk files with spaces using command prompt?

Tags: windows-8, command-line

I couldn't seem to find the answer. I know that to run .lnk files it would be like:
start shortcut.lnk

It works on shortcuts without spaces. But let's say that the shortcut has a space on it, for example, "short cut", I can't seem to run it.

I tried running:

```
start short cut.lnk
```

And it will only read "short".

I also tried running:

```
start "short cut.lnk"
```

And it will open a new command prompt running as administrator on the same directory.

Comment: It a Windows behavior, period. If you are calling a .lnk or .url, or .exe... if there are spaces in the path, you need "Path\and the file.ext"

Comment: Well, I could swear that double quotes will work. But in that case they don't. See my [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vM33W.png)

Comment: @AthomSfere That sucks... thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: @YungPizzay It's strange that just typing `start Short Cut.lnk` didn't work for you, I just tested it and it worked first time.

Comment: @nixda: Just tried "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\Windows Notepad.lnk" and of course Notepad popped up right on cue. No need even to use `start`.

Comment: @Karan, the start command is designed to run a separate CLI window. It's useful if you have a batch file that runs multiple processes and you don't want them to clutter your main cmd window.

Comment: @MichaelFrank: I know that, but there's no indication the OP's running a shortcut to a CLI program. `start` is not required if you have a shortcut to a GUI program that will anyway have its own window.

Comment: Thats not a duplicate as you can see after Michaels' answer

Answer (score 8):

You need to double quote the text before the extension like so:

[image]